# What does 'ignore reason: pending' in cucumber tests means?

Tags: cucumber, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I am using `wdio v4.12.0` and `wdio-cucumber-framework` which is using `cucumber v1.3.3` One of tests is ignored and only information in cmd output is that `ignore reason: pending`. All previous and later steps are executed without error.

> [field with default name is visible] Test ignored: field with default name is visible, ignore reason: pending

Feature file:

```
Scenario: User is able to add field
  Given user is on fields page
  When user creates new field with default name
  Then field with default name is visible
```

What can be cause of skipping this step? What does pending means (is it just unresolved promise or what)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe scenarios are marked as pending when Cucumber cannot find the underlying definition for one or more steps. In this case, it probably cannot find the step definition for "Then field with default name is visible" so check if you have implemented this definition.

Comment: There was ambiguity between `/^field with default name is visible$/` and `/^field (.*) is visible$/`, so you were right.

Answer (score 0):

Pending step means the step has not been implemented. If Cucumber cannot find your glue, it will suggest snippets with how to implement your steps.